# Exceeding Relay maximum switching frequency

Tags: relay, safety, failure

I read in the datasheet of the [DOLD OA5611](http://www.dold.com/datenblaetter/Leiterplattenrelais/OA5611_en.pdf) that the maximum relay cycles/s is 10 cycles/s.  Now I want to know what are the risks for the relay if I control it with a switching frequency more than 10 Hz. It's not specified in the datasheet what the conditions for the current and voltage for the maximum switching frequency are.

Otherwise i find in other relays [datahseet](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/400-00052-Omron-12V-Relay-Datasheet.pdf) that there is two values for the maximum operating frequency:
Mechanical max operating frequency which is 18000 operations/hour,
Electrical max operating frequency 1800 operations/hour @ rated load.
My questions:

1. What is the used maximum operating frequency to respect in the datasheet.
2. Can we exceed the Electrical max operating frequency if the relay is used with current and voltage less than the rated load.

From what I understood we can use the relay with frequency more than the Electrical max operating frequency if the used current and voltage are less than the rated load. But we cannot exceed the mechanical max operating frequency in any condition. am I right ?

Comment: If you need to switch a relay more than 10 times a second, you probably shouldn't be using a relay.

Comment: using any device outside its specifications is likely to result in an undefined failure mode.

Comment: WHat do you mean by undefined failure mode, sticking relay or open circuit

Comment: Unless you've built a relay computer and you're overclocking it to 15Hz for fun ... don't.

Comment: @NickJohnson sometimes they specifies in the datasheets the current and the voltage used for the maximum frequency, so if you use less than these values of current and voltage you can use your relay with the maximum switching frequency

Comment: @codo "Undefined" means just that - it could fail in any way, at any time. I don't follow your last statement at all.

Comment: undefined means I - and the manufacturer - don't know.

Comment: 1min and 7 seconds into this might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mclp9QmCGs

Comment: i think is depends on the number of cycles of your relay, if you use more frequency than you increase the failure frequency

Comment: Not to mention, this relay is rated at 3e5 - that's 300,000 - cycles. At 10Hz, you'll exceed that in just 8 hours.

Comment: You aren't confusing switching frequency - the number of times you can make the relay turn on and off - with the frequency of the signal you want to switch are you?

Comment: Is depend on the used current see the graph switching cycles vs switching current

Comment: @Icy no is the same thing, every time that your contact is closed in every command

Comment: @codo Yes, because higher current induces more damage to the contacts due to arcs when they open and close. The relay will still wear out very quickly if you're switching at high speeds for sustained periods.

Answer (score 4):

Likely it will sit there and quiver - it's a mechanical system, the parts have mass, it takes time to accelerate the mass...

If you need something that switches fast, a solid-state relay is a convenient off the shelf "brick" or a power transistor may be more appropriate - a mechanical relay is not the tool for the job.

Comment: I'm not sure is depend on the application: if your load is sensitive to the voltage drop this can cause problem because your SSR can fail to close (short-circuit) this is very dangerous for safety applications.

Comment: ...it's also "very dangerous for safety applications" to run a device outside of specifications.

Comment: No, if your device fail to open instead of close is more safe, this is the case of a safety relay, the use of SSR is not a solution in safe applications.